# Why Data Virtualization in WPF loads all pages on some machines and not all machines?

Tags: wpf, virtualization

I have implemented data virtualization in wpf using datagrid with itemsource as observable collection. But in some machines the grid requests for only first page and for other machines it requests for all pages, the grid is divided into.

Currently, the pagesize for a particular page is 100 in my grid.
Also, i am sending parallel requests to fetch initially first 300 pages and when the user scrolls down the data for remaining pages are loaded.
But in some machines all data is loaded irrespective of user scrolling which is wrong and i am not getting why all pages are requested instead of just the first page.

Please let me know what am I missing or unable to understand. Any suggestions are welcomed.

Thank-you!

Comment: Are you sure you mean data virtualization, not UI virtualization? There is a subtle difference.

Comment: Yes, i mean data virtualization and not UI virtualization.

Comment: I'd need to see some code to help you.

Comment: I implemented data virtualization as given in following [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization]